# How to read data from .txt file skipping 1st row

Tags: c#

How can I read data from `.txt` file?
My data file looks like this http://prntscr.com/nl4c3l
I've found `OpenFileDialog` class and successfully read 1st row using code below, but i dont know how to skip 1st row and start reading from second.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog.FileName);
string line = sr.ReadLine();
string[] names = line.Split(',');
int counter = 0;

foreach (String s in names)
{
    DataAttribute attribute;
    if (counter!=names.Length-1)
    {
        attribute = new DataAttribute(s);
    }
    else
    {
        attribute = new DataDecision(s);
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Make up your mind if you want to skip 1st row or 1st column.

Comment: Yeah, skip first row, my bad. I want to start reading from 2nd one, because 1st row is name of object i want to create and every other are values of these objects.

Comment: Call readline 2 times? IMHO use linq skip call readalllines...

Comment: Just access the data you need. `string[] rows = sr.ReadAllLines(); string[] columnNames = rows[0].Split(','); for(int i=1; i< rows.Lenght; i++)`

Comment: That's a Csv . I will recommend using an external Library for reading/writing csv. Like CSV helper this way the whole things can be build easly. Like `using( texReader (Path)) using(CsvReader) MyList= CsvReader.GetRecords<MyType>()`. one line for config like has header, comma or ; as separator. and bam it's done.

Comment: Little question are those value string or enum?

Comment: @xdtTransform its just txt file that maybe looks like csv, its school project, my 1st contact with c# i dont really want to use libraries, but thanks for advice. They are all strings

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ReadAllLines`, and Skip method, like:

```
 var AllExceptFirstLine = File.ReadAllLines(FileName).Skip(1).ToList();
```

Comment: An explanation as to why the OP code isnt working would be useful as well. Great solution as well!

Comment: What does ToList() do? AllExceptFirstLine becomes list?

Comment: @Dicanio, Yes exactly. Skip return an Ienumerable so we may need to convert it to List

Comment: Thanks, but i will change it to ToArray() because I have to know coordinates of every record.

Comment: Uhm, just realized every record is one letter, how can i use Split() in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Using and External lib like [CSV Helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper) will help in parsing the data into usable objects.

For simple Csv with no need of mapping(csv header match property, no complexe type or convertion needed), you can simply:

```
public class Weather {
    public string Outlook {get;set;}
    public string Temperature{get;set;}
    public string Humidity{get;set;}
    public string Wind{get;set;}
    public string Decision{get;set;}
}

void Main()
{
    var records = new List<Weather>();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Weather>();
    }
}
```

Comment: From this point handleing Error, Bad type, Missing data, or convertion from string to enum for Wind strong is just as simple.

Comment: Weather is just example, it will be decision tree so it's pretty pointless to create class for every case, sorry for not explaining it before..

Comment: @Dicanio, No problemo, It can also do  `dynamic` just drop the class and `csv.GetRecords<dynamic>();`; And I'm not working for them, it's free. I only provide this recommendation because it really helps getting the job done. You want to save the data [Bim](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/writing/write-dynamic-objects/).

Comment: I'll use it later because my team wants to have csv load option, but not now. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try using *Linq*, `Skip`; providing that you want an array of custom class `Weather`

```
using System.Linq;

...

Weather[] records = File
  .ReadLines(openFileDialog.FileName)
  .Skip(1)                          // Skip 1st line
  .Select(line => line.Split(','))  // Convert each line starting from the 2nd
  .Select(items => new Weather() {  // into custom Weather classes
     Outlook = items[0],            //TODO: add necessary conversions if required 
     Temperature = items[1], 
     Humidity = items[2], 
     Wind = items[3], 
     Decision = items[4]
   })
  .ToArray();                       // organized as an array
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just repeat `line = sr.ReadLine();`. the `ReadLine()` function increments lines automatically with every call.